# QT Designer Stylesheet Border Properties

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I'm a bit new to QT Stylesheets. I'm using QT Designer. For my frame, when I type this which I got from an online tutorial, I get a nice white rounded border.

```
#frame1 {border-radius: 15px; border: 3px solid white;}
```

[image]

When I try to use some different border properties that I'm reading in the docs, such as this, I can't see a border.

```
#frame1 {border-radius: 15px; border-width: 3px;
border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}
```

[image]

Can I make the second way work? I want to be able to choose from a wide array of colors.

Comment: I think you just need to add `border-style: solid;` to make it look like the first picture.

Comment: Thanks Roknus. That worked.